# The following error occurred converting from cell to double:

Tags: matlab

i am searching a folder for text files and i am adding those files found into a new array called mytext

this is my code

```
function fileList = removeElements(fileArray)

x = 1;
mytext = [];

for idx = 1:numel(fileArray)

if (~isempty(strfind(fileArray(idx),'.txt')  )) 

    mytext(x) = fileArray(idx)
    x=x+1;  

end 

end
```

end

But iam getting a error

```
??? The following error occurred converting from cell to double:
Error using ==> double
Conversion to double from cell is not possible.

Error in ==> removeElements at 10
        mytext(x) = fileArray(idx)
```

How can i overcome this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are generally stored in cell arrays.  So you need to index with `{}`, not `()`:

```
mytext{x} = fileArray{idx};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the *.txt files from a list via

```
txtFiles = allFiles(cellfun(@(c)(~isempty(strfind('.txt',c))),allFiles));
```

The ~isempty(strfind('.txt',c)) construction returns true if the string c contains the string '.txt' and false otherwise. The allFiles(...) construction returns a cell array of just those elements of the cell array allFiles for which the cellfun construction returns true.